# How to add rowspan in datatable using laravel and jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm using datatable for showing my data into client side, but I still don't know how to add rowspan in my datatable, I wanna ask how to do that? I will show my code and my example data to give more information about my problem.

**My Example Data :**

```
$my_data = [
   {
      "accepted_data": "2021-06-18",
      "employee_charge": [
         "Drawing",
         "BQ",
         "Drawing"
      ],
      "employee_name": [
         "John",
         "Doe",
         "Skye"
      ],
      "employee_charge": [
         1,
         2,
         3
      ],
      "owner": "Mr Uy",
      "project_location": "Indonesia",
      "project_name": "Mantan Terindah",
      "scope": "MEP",
      "status": "win",
      "submitted_target": "2021-10-01"
   },
   {
      "accepted_data": "2021-07-18",
      "employee_charge": [
         "Drawing",
         "BQ",
      ],
      "employee_name": [
         "Poe",
         "Dul",
      ],
      "employee_charge": [
         4,
         5
      ],
      "owner": "Mr Kitaa",
      "project_location": "Japan",
      "project_name": "Yakusoku no Bashou",
      "scope": "Drawing",
      "status": "On Progress",
      "submitted_target": "2021-12-31"
   }
];
```

**My Controller :**

```
$columns = array();
foreach ($my_data as $field) {
   for ($child = 0; $child < count($field['employee_name']); $child++) {
      $start++;
      $row = array();

      $row[] = $start;
      $row[] = $field['project_name'];
      $row[] = $field['project_location'];
      $row[] = $field['owner'];
      $row[] = $field['scope'];
      $row[] = date('d F Y', strtotime($field['accepted_date']));
      $row[] = date('d F Y', strtotime($field['submitted_target']));
      $row[] = $field['employee_name'][$child];
      $row[] = $field['employee_charge'][$child];
      $row[] = $field['status'];

      $columns[] = $row;
   }
}
```

**My Jquery :**

```
let table = $("#table").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
       url: 'my_url/get-data',
       method: "GET",
       dataType: "json"
    }
});
```

**My Result :**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" style="width: 100%">
    <thead class="text-center">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">No</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Project Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Location</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Owner</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Scope</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Accepted (Date)</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Submitted Target (Date)</th>
            <th colspan="2">PIC</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>BQ / Drawing</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-center">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Mantan Terindah</td>
          <td>Indonesia</td>
          <td>Mr Uy</td>
          <td>MEP</td>
          <td>18 June 2021</td>
          <td>01 October 2021</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
          <td>Win</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Mantan Terindah</td>
          <td>Indonesia</td>
          <td>Mr Uy</td>
          <td>MEP</td>
          <td>18 June 2021</td>
          <td>01 October 2021</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>BQ</td>
          <td>Win</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Mantan Terindah</td>
          <td>Indonesia</td>
          <td>Mr Uy</td>
          <td>MEP</td>
          <td>18 June 2021</td>
          <td>01 October 2021</td>
          <td>Skye</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
          <td>Win</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Yakusoku no Bashou</td>
          <td>Japan</td>
          <td>Mr Kitaa</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
          <td>18 July 2021</td>
          <td>31 December 2021</td>
          <td>Poe</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
          <td>On Progress</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Yakusoku no Bashou</td>
          <td>Japan</td>
          <td>Mr Kitaa</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
          <td>18 July 2021</td>
          <td>31 December 2021</td>
          <td>Dul</td>
          <td>BQ</td>
          <td>On Progress</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Expectation :**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" style="width: 100%">
    <thead class="text-center">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">No</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Project Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Location</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Owner</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Scope</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Accepted (Date)</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Submitted Target (Date)</th>
            <th colspan="2">PIC</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>BQ / Drawing</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-center">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3">1</td>
          <td rowspan="3">Mantan Terindah</td>
          <td rowspan="3">Indonesia</td>
          <td rowspan="3">Mr Uy</td>
          <td rowspan="3">MEP</td>
          <td rowspan="3">18 June 2021</td>
          <td rowspan="3">01 October 2021</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
          <td rowspan="3">Win</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>BQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Skye</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">2</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Yakusoku no Bashou</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Japan</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Mr Kitaa</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Drawing</td>
          <td rowspan="2">18 July 2021</td>
          <td rowspan="2">31 December 2021</td>
          <td>Poe</td>
          <td>Drawing</td>
          <td rowspan="2">On Progress</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dul</td>
          <td>BQ</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If there is information that is not clear, you can tell me again and I will explain it again, thank you.

Comment: DataTables does not support `rowspan` in the body of a table. See the "HTML" section of the [installation manual](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML): _"while DataTables supports colspan and rowspan in the table's header and footer, they are not supported in the table's tbody and must not be present."_.

Comment: Having said that, you may be interested in [the rowgroup extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/simple.html), or in other ways to [fake a rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673219/12567365).

Comment: ok sir I will try it with your suggestion, I still confused how to solve my problem because I need that rowspan or colspan method, any suggestion sir?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know any way to use rowspan in the body of a DataTable. If you find a solution you can post it as an answer! I wish you good luck.