# Display dividing line after a group of rows not every row in a DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my `dataTable` i am populating it with telephone numbers but these numbers can be duspliacted as they may have a different extension (for example) so rather than displaying the `row` divider on evey line i'd like to know if its possible to display after a number with numerious `rows`?

Below is an example with fake numbers in.
[image]

**Note:** its only if the telephone number matches not any other column

Comment: Check the manual, https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: You can create "fake" rowspans: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673219/12567365). This is similar (but not identical) to the effect you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the rowGroup extension located [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/).

Since no code was provided I am going to assume that your Phone Number data is just called "Number". You can do the following in your DataTable JS code.

```js
       rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: [
                'Number'
            ],
            startRender: function(rows, group, level) {
                var all;
                if (level === 0) {
                    top = group;
                    all = group;
                } else if (level === 1) {
                    parent = top + group;
                    all = parent;
                    if (!collapsedGroups[top]) {
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!collapsedGroups[parent]) {
                        return;
                    }
                    all = top + parent + group;
                }
                var collapsed = !collapsedGroups[all];

                rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
                    r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
                });
              
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append('<td colspan="12" style="text-align: left;"">' + group + " (" + rows.count() + ")" + "</td>")
                    .attr('data-name', all)
                    .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
            },
        },
```