# How can I hide the ungrouped row values when using DataTables rowGroup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the rowGroup plugin with DataTables and a custom startRender function to produce the following table output:

```
Order Number    Invoice Date    SKU             Description
‌472653          2/8/2021        
‌472653          2/8/2021        269-MD-CD       product abc
‌472653          2/8/2021        267-MD-CD       product XYZ
‌472657          2/5/2021        
‌472657          2/5/2021        269-MD-CD       product abc
‌472657          2/5/2021        QUINP03         product FGH
‌472665          2/5/2021        ‌
‌472665          2/5/2021        ‌MDVD-2004       product MNO
‌472665          2/5/2021        269-MD-CD       ‌product abc
‌472679          2/4/2021        
‌472679          2/4/2021        269-MD-CD       product abc
‌472680          2/11/2021       
‌472680          2/11/2021       269-MD-CD       product abc
```

I would like the grouped row values to not be shown in the ungrouped rows, like so:

```
Order Number    Invoice Date    SKU             Description
‌472653          2/8/2021        
‌                                269-MD-CD       product abc
‌                                267-MD-CD       product XYZ
‌472657          2/5/2021        
‌                                269-MD-CD       product abc
‌                                QUINP03         product FGH
‌472665          2/5/2021        ‌
‌                                MDVD-2004       product MNO
‌                                269-MD-CD       ‌product abc
‌472679          2/4/2021        
‌                                269-MD-CD       product abc
‌472680          2/11/2021       
‌                                269-MD-CD       product abc
```

How can go about "hiding" or removing those values from the cells?

Comment: If you already use a custom render function, why don't you check if the value of the previous row is the same and then leave it blank?

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, you can try using "fake" rowspans in your DataTable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67668951/paginate-datatables-with-rowspans/67673219#67673219) for an example. Caveat - I have not tried combining that approach with the rowGroup plugin.

Comment: @Claus Bönnhoff the custom renderer is only for the group row, not each row.