# How can I convert this complex table into Datatables since it does not support rowspan?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I know datatables does not support rowspan. But I have to convert this complex table into a datatable, so if anyone has any suggestions or examples, please advise.
[image]

Comment: Not an answer, just one possible approach, as a starting point: [Paginate datatables with rowspans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67668951/12567365). You can do more research into [possibly similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdatatables%5D+rowspan), as well.

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself? Is there an attempt you can share?

Comment: Yes, I will post my work tomorrow. I logged off from my computer. I used row grouping feature of datatables.