# How to stretch a cell to all table headers using DataTables?

Tags: html, datatables

[image]

I want to have this table structure in my page and i am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/)

```
<table id="journalEntryTable" class="display table table-bordered border border-1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Particulars</th>
              <th>Debit</th>
              <th>Credit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>April 1</td>
              <td>Furniture AC</td>
              <td>7000</td>
              <td>7000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam ipsam illum illo, eius dolore distinctio ipsum nam praesentium suscipit autem aperiam at dicta voluptas nisi earum vel consequuntur! Corporis, reprehenderit.</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

however when i have the code above it shows an error

[image]

How do i make the row span of 4 without having datatables see it as an error?

Comment: From the [official manual](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML): "_Please also note that while DataTables supports `colspan` and `rowspan` in the table's header and footer, they are not supported in the table's `tbody` and must not be present_".

Comment: You can try [faking it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673219/12567365) - but that can be tricky.

Comment: You can get a colspan-like effect if you use the [RowGroup](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/simple.html) extension.